# Error correction within the long read

Tags: nanopore, long-reads, minion, literature-search, minimap2

I am going to get some data from plasmid sequencing to identify SNPs on the plasmids. What is done in the lab is the following:

- The plasmids are purified by size.
- We amplify the plasmids using the phi29 polymerase. The polymerase will go through the plasmid multiple times. Hence we get the same sequence concatenated multiple times. **My question is related to this step:**
- Finally, We sequence it using Oxford Nanopore.

My question is:

On step two, I wrote that "we get the same sequence concatenated multiple times". For me, this a potential source of information to correct the base calls prior to aligning them to the reference. Since you have the same sequence multiple times (concatemers).

What I would like to know is if there is a tool that uses the information of the concatemers to improve the base calls. I have tried to find some methods but found none. I know that PacBio has a similar flavour using the "circular consensus calling", but I have not found any methodological explanation.

thanks!

Comment: Nice project! Do you know the length of the (linearized) plasmids? I haven't heard of any tool similar to this but I don't usually analyze long-reads sequencing data. Good luck with your project

Comment: I don't, the project aim is to detect which plasmids a bacteria contains. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Then the project is more complicated, because if you don't know the length of the repetitions of the plasmid you'll need to search for a range of size of the repetitions, which can be longer/more difficult (depending on how you compare the different portions of the reads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a tool to do this called R2C2 by the Vollmers lab at UC Santa Cruz.

https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2018/06/04/338020

Comment: That was definetively the tool I was looking for. Thank you very much!